# Error while install exists Flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Error while `dart run build_runner build`

Log: https://pastebin.com/k0gpWuun
Verbose Log: https://pastebin.com/BNgVh6pV

pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.9
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.8
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.0.6
  dio: ^4.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.1.0
  json_serializable: ^4.1.4
  build: ^2.1.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
```

flutter clean and other cmd's not working for me
Reinstall Flutter, migrate to Linux (heh), reinstall sdk's

Comment: Please check you have downloaded a valid SDK according to device configs.

Comment: You have problem in token_response.dart file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your `pubspec.yaml` file to

`dependencies`:

```
  analyzer: ^5.4.0 <- add this
```

`dev_dependencies`:

```
 build_runner: ^2.3.3 <- add into dev_dependecies
```

Comment: `Because json_serializable ^4.0.1 depends on analyzer >=0.41.2 <2.0.0 and coffee_pwa depends on analyzer ^5.4.0, json_serializable ^4.0.1 is forbidden.
So, because coffee_pwa depends on json_serializable ^4.1.4, version solving failed.
`

Comment: you can use by downgrade the package version @Consolas